# Pushing to an array within node request()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to build a simple webscraper using [Request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) and [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio).

The goal right now is to scrape the destination page (in this case http://bukk.it), grab the text from the target selectors on the page, and push it to an array that I can use in other functions.

I understand that `request()` is executing asynchronously, but do not know how to the scraped data visible outside the function.

**example.js**

```
// dependencies
var request = require('request')
, cheerio = require('cheerio');

// variables
var url = 'http://bukk.it/'; // url to scrape
var bukkits = []; // hold our scraped data

request(url, function(err, resp, body){

  if (err) {
    return
  }

  $ = cheerio.load(body);
  // for each of our targets (within the request body)...
  $('td a').each(function(){
    content = $(this).text();
    // I would love to populate the bukkits array for use later...
    bukkits.push(content);
  })
  console.log(bukkits.length); // everything is working inside request
});

console.log(bukkits.length); // nothing, because request is asynchronous?

// that's cool but... how do I actually get the data from the request into bukkits[] ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, your entire program must now take place inside the callback. No code after that callback will ever have access to data that was retrieved asynchronously and passed to the callback.

This isn't as bad as it sounds. You can use named functions, like so:

```
request(url, onRequestDone);

function onRequestDone(err, resp, body) {
  var bukkits = []; // not global, make it local

  // as above

  doMoreWork(bukkits);
}

function doMoreWork(bukkits) {
  // stuff after the parsing goes here.
}
```

Comment: Ah, I feared as much : ) My intention was to have this code as one part of an express based app; i'm not sure how to wrap my head around incorporating that.

Comment: Generally express-based apps have most of their work take place inside route handlers, which from what I recall have a `next` function that you call when all the asynchronous processing is done. Simple don't call `next` until all the work is done.

Answer (score 0):

Your code ends before the request completes.

use the forever version of the agent

```
request = require('request').forever;
```

for use setTimeout to keep your program running.

```
setTimeout(function(){}, 1000000);
```

to use the values later on, it needs to also be done after the request call completes.